# Spy, Stub or Mock? Or None of the Above?

Tags: mocha.js, sinon

I'm using Mocha to test a Node.js API. I need to test a route that checks whether an update is available. The route accepts a version number of what's currently installed and compares it with an available version retrieved via an HTTP request.

To get the latest version available, a model method is called. `Client.availableVersion()` makes the HTTP request, does some simple manipulation and passes the available version to a callback function. Fairly straightforward stuff, but now I want to test my `update()` route and I need to be able to control what is returned by `Client.availableVersion()`.

Having read the Mocha docs and the [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) docs I was referred to...I'm stuck. It sounds like Sinon will handle what I need, but the implementation has me a little confused.

Here's a snippet from my routes method:

```
update: function( req, res, next ) {
  var installedVersion = req.params.version;

  client.availableVersion( function( err, availableVersion ) {
    if( !err ) {
      if( parseInt( installedVersion, 10 ) < parseInt( availableVersion, 10 ) ) {
        // SEND UPDATE AVAILABLE RESPONSE
      }

      // SEND NO UPDATE AVAILABLE RESPONSE
    }
    else {
      res.send( 500, err );
    }
  })
}
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely go with stubs. http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs

I would use the `stub.yields(...)`

```
var next = sinon.spy()
var err = ... //Whatever object you want to pass as error or undefined
var availbleVersion = ... // A fake of the response the method is supposed to give
client.availableVersion = sinon.stub().yields(err, availableVersion);

myRoute.update(fakeReq, fakeRes, next);

//All you expectations
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to do exactly what I need it to do.